difficulty to understand the code, and maybe the concept itself (recursion problem)
this code below is from Grokking Algorithms book that is an exercise for the functional programming/recursion and an application for the D&C concept. the function finds the maximum number in a list.
what i don't understand here is when the return statement at the bottom will get executed, i feel like every time i reach line 16 ( sub_max = max(arr) ) i go up again at the start of the code, or the return statement will get executed everytime and i have a problem in my understanding of the concept. please help me there and thank you!
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <typename T>
T max(std::vector<T> arr) {
    if (arr.empty()) throw std::invalid_argument("Cannot select max value from empty sequence");
    if (arr.size() == 1) return arr.at(0);

    T back = arr.back();
    arr.pop_back();

    T sub_max = max(arr);
    
    return back > sub_max ? back : sub_max; 
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> array = {1, 5, 10, 25, 16, 1};
    cout << max(array) << endl;

    std::vector<int> negative_array = {-1, -5, -10, -25, -16};
    cout << max(negative_array) << endl;
}

give me some hands in this

Because of arr.pop_back() the vector will decrease in size, until the condition if (arr.size() == 1) is true. Then that recursive call will end and you'll get to the final return statement. Which will go back to the previous call, etc. It would be easy to see if you used some pen and paper and a debugger.

When functions are called, they also return and execution continues below that. This is true whether or not the function call happens to be a recursive call. Every call to max will return at some point, and then that return will execute. It will execute several times: once for every execution of max that didn't get into the base case of if (arr.size() == 1)

There's really no "magic" about recursion. It's all just a plain standard function call, like any other.

The return back > sub_max ? back : sub_max; is used to go back to the previous function call.
Let's see what function max does:

Check if arr is empty or not, it will give an error if the arr is empty.
Check if the size of arr is only one, if it's only one, just return the only number inside the arr variable.
Create a variable back that is retrieved from the last item of arr.
Delete the last data in arr (the one that we save in the back variable).
Recursion (call the function max again and passing the arr variable that has been modified) and store the result returned on sub_max variable.
Return which one is bigger, back or sub_max.

Let's simulate the recursion with std::vector<int> arr = {1, 5, 10, 25, 16, 1};

1.1 -> Check for empty arr and if arr only has one item, it doesn't
1.2 -> It will create a variable back and put 1 inside it and delete the 1 at the back of arr which makes arr -> {1, 5, 10, 25, 16}
1.3 -> It will call max function again and it will pass arr -> {1, 5, 10, 25, 16} the result from the function will be save inside sub_max

===================================================================

2.1 -> Check for empty arr and if arr only has one item, it doesn't
2.2 -> It will create a variable back and put 16 inside it and delete the 16 which makes arr -> {1, 5, 10, 25}
2.3 -> It will call max function again and it will pass arr -> {1, 5, 10, 25} the result from the function will be save inside sub_max

===================================================================

3.1 -> Check for empty arr and if arr only has one item, it doesn't
3.2 -> It will create a variable back and put 25 inside it and delete the 25 at the back of arr which makes arr -> {1, 5, 10}
3.3 -> It will call max function again and it will pass arr -> {1, 5, 10} the result from the function will be save inside sub_max

===================================================================

4.1 -> Check for empty arr and if arr only has one item, it doesn't
4.2 -> It will create a variable back and put 10 inside it and delete the 25 at the back of arr which makes arr -> {1, 5}
4.3 -> It will call max function again and it will pass arr -> {1, 5} the result from the function will be save inside sub_max

===================================================================

5.1 -> Check for empty arr and if arr only has one item, it doesn't
5.2 -> It will create a variable back and put 5 inside it and delete the 5 at the back of arr which makes arr -> {1}
5.3 -> It will call max function again and it will pass arr -> {1} the result from the function will be save inside sub_max

===================================================================

6.1 -> Check for empty arr and if arr only has one item, it's not empty but it only has one item, it will execute return arr.at(0) which has 1 in it to 5th function call

===================================================================

5.4 -> sub_max store 1 from 6th function call
5.5 -> Now it reaches the end, and compare values between sub_max and back on 5th function call, because back is 5 and sub_max is 1, it will return 5 to 4th function call

===================================================================

4.4 -> sub_max store 5 from 5th function call
4.5 -> Now it reaches the end, and compare values between sub_max and back on 4th function call, because back is 10 and sub_max is 5, it will return 10 to 3rd function call

===================================================================

3.4 -> sub_max store 10 from 4th function call
3.5 -> Now it reaches the end, and compare values between sub_max and back on 3rd function call, because back is 25 and sub_max is 10, it will return 25 to 2nd function call

===================================================================

2.4 -> sub_max store 25 from 3rd function call
2.5 Now it reaches the end, and compare values between sub_max and back on 2nd function call, because back is 16 and sub_max is 25, it will return 25 to 1st function call

===================================================================

1.4 -> sub_max store 25 from 2nd function call
1.5 -> Now it reaches the end, and compare values between sub_max and back on 2nd function call, because back is 1 and sub_max is 25, it will return 25 to main()

So this function will return the max number inside arr which is 25. Hope this helps!

You do not reach line 16.
if (arr.size() == 1) return arr.at(0);

Will end the recursive calls as soon as the array size is reduced to 1

Just use pen and paper next time to evaluate how the array develops.
the last element of the array gets removed and saved in back then the array get called with the same function again until the array-length is 1 then the first element gets returned and then its just picking up the return statements:
{1, 5, 10, 25, 16, 1}

back = 1
{1, 5, 10, 25, 16}

    sub_max = max({1, 5, 10, 25, 16})
            back = 16
            sub_max = max({1, 5, 10, 25})
            
                back = 25
                sub_max = max({1, 5, 10})
                
                    back = 10
                    sub_max = max({1, 5})
                    
                        back = 5
                        sub_max = max({1})
                        
                        //now array size = 1 , so return arr.at(0)
                        
                        return 5 > 1 ? 5 : 1
                    return 10 > 5 ? 10 : 5
                return 25 > 10 ? 25 : 10
            return 16 > 25 ? 16 : 25
    return 1 > 25 ? 1 : 25

